# Can I see the piece of code in java - where every class is extending the Object class?

Tags: java

If I am declaring a class(Example Dog.java), where it is written in JVM that it will extend the Object class. I want to see the piece of code where Dog is extending the Object class.

**Update** 
I referred [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-4.html) as @Jack suggested. As per document While making the class structure, JVM will identify the superclass using `constant_pool` if there is no superclass then index of `constant_pool` should be **zero** and if there is valid superclass then the value of `constant_pool` will be a valid index in the pool, But my question is, if the value is zero then for all the classes having 0 indexes JVM will assign them index of Object class from pool by default or it modifies the class file and add "**extends Object**" in the classes.

Comment: why do you have to know something like that?

Comment: Look at the byte code, `javap`

Comment: Do you really mean the JVM, or the source of Dog.java?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am curious to know how the creator of java implemented this.

Comment: *I am curious to know how the creator of java implemented this* -> then how should anyone **but** the creator know this?

Comment: It's probably just something like (pseudocode) `if (no specified parent class) extend Object`.

Comment: @SteveSmith I want to see the code. It must be in the present in the java bin package so I have written JVM as a whole.

Comment: You could try looking at the source of OpenJDK.

Comment: The title of this question is kind of misleading. *Everything* in Java ultimately extends the Object class, so trivially you can find this by looking at any Java code at all. Based on the body of the question and the answer you accepted I don't think that this is what you're asking, though.

Answer (score 4):

How this is implemented resides in the `.class` format, not in the bytecode per se.

Basically in the header of the `.class` file there is an index which specifies an entry inside the `constant_pool` section of the `.class` in which the class is identified by name. If no super class is specified in the source, then, at time of `.class` generation, `Object` will be used.

You can find more informations [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-4.html).

Comment: In the reference document, it is written that if no superclass is found then `constant_pool_index` will be zero. but what next? 
Where `JVM` will assign Object as a superclass for all the classes having superclass `constant_pool_index` zero.